# Collecting webGL app framerate histogram data

Tags: webgl, three.js, scenejs, copperlicht

I'm thinking to stick for a particular framework to work for my academic course but only based on results I should prove. I want to plot the graph for all the three frameworks where No.of Vertices is one axis and FPS (threshold is 60) is on other axis. Will that be good enough to take single predefined model in formats like obj, collada, json etc and load it in three frameworks?  Then log the frame rate and number of vertices to some external file and thereafter use the data for plotting a graph to report the best framework among three based on Performance parameter. But I'm looking for some boilerplate codes for all these frameworks to load different models (can be used for number of vertices dimension in my graph) and log the frame rates for every second to external file. This is the approach I've been thinking. But couldn't find much help on this on internet. I wish someone could help me?

Comment: Three.js examples come with a FPS history graph. You could take a look on that as an example.

Comment: MikkoOhtamaa, I want to access the Framerate of Histogram to external file, Could you please suggest me how could I do that.

Comment: There is a FileSystem API in HTML5  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ for writing data from Javascript to an external file

Comment: MikkoOhtamaa Thanks for the reply. But my question intention was "How to access the FPS from histogram?" Saving it is secondary task. I hope you got my point.

Comment: The best way to find out is to read and study the source code: https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, I tweaked it, thanks for the idea. It's working fine.

Comment: Ok. I'll add an answer so we can close the question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get FPS histogram data using stats.js library which is bundled with all Three.js examples

https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js

Exporting the collected data to a file can be done using HTML5 File System API.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used stats.js to get FPS data. I'm looking forward for the article you mentioned.